# Complex eigenvalues of real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given a matrix 
>   $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
> 40  &  -29 & -11\\ \ -18  &  30\ & -12 \\\ \ 26 &24 & -50   \end{pmatrix}$$
>   has a certain complex number $l\neq0$ as an eigenvalue. Which of the following must also be an eigenvalue of $A$:
>   $$l+20, l-20, 20-l, -20-l?$$

It seems that complex eigenvalues occur in conjugate pairs. It is clear that the determinant of the matrix is zero, then $0$ seems to be one of the eigenvalues.

Please suggest.

Comment: In English, we use "eigenvalue" and "eigenvector" (single word).

Comment: $\text{tr}(A) = \sum_i \lambda_i,$ so $ 20 = \lambda + l + 0.$

Comment: how it is clear that determinant is 0?by hand calculation?

Comment: @Tsotsi I suppose it is clear by hand calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The *trace* of the matrix is $40+30+(-50)$.  As you observed, $0$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Given matrix is a $3\times 3$ matrix(odd order) with one complex eigen value.Complex eigen value will ocur in a conjugate pair.  You must have noticed that 0 is its real eigen value while $l$ is given complex eigen value. Find remaining eigen value by using above hints and that must be complex one.

Comment: @srijan i do not understand why 0 is an eigen value, explain kor

Comment: @Tsotsi As the determinant of the matrix is zero which shows that matrix $A$ is singular hence it must have atleast one eigenvalue 0

Comment: @Tsotsi: Each row has sum $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. It is clear when you see it, but if one doesn't notice, it looks as if one needs to do the full determinant calculation.